# How do you apply "Pick" to multiple sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following list:

```
lis1={{{A3,T3},{A3,T4}},{{A3,T3}},{{A3,T3},{A4,T4},{A3,T1}}}
```

Which is also accompanied by an `Association` of:

```
 assoc = <|A1 -> 10, A2 -> 2, A3 -> 10, A4 -> 10, T1 -> 10, T2 -> 11, 
  T3 -> 10, T4 -> 14|>
```

If I then do `ReplaceAll[lis1,assoc]`, I get a new list:

```
lis2={{{10, 10}, {10, 14}}, {{10, 10}}, {{10, 10}, {10, 14}, {10, 10}}}
```

What I would like to do is use the `Pick` function and pull out the sublists in `lis1` only if their numerical values given by the association are the same.  That would yield me the desired list of:

```
lisfinal={{{A3,T3}},{{A3,T3}},{{A3,T3},{A3,T1}}}
```

To perform this without any sublists you can use `Pick[lis1,Equal@@@(lis1/.assoc)]`, but I'm having trouble using that same function with multiple sublists present.  I've tried both `Map` and `Apply`, but I don't think I'm getting the syntax correct.

Edit: I have changed the association values to reflect my question

Comment: `ReplaceAll[lis1,assoc]` gives `{{{6, 12}, {6, 14}}, {{6, 12}}, {{6, 12}, {10, 14}, {6, 10}}}`, not  `{{{10, 10}, {10, 14}}, {{10, 10}}, {{10, 10}, {10, 14}, {10, 10}}}`

Comment: Sorry about that, I had the wrong association values there, I've edited the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Pick[lis1, Apply[Equal, lis1 /. assoc, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Pick, if I understand your parameters:

```
GatherBy[#, Map[assoc]][[1]] & /@ lis1
```

> ```
> {{{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A3, T1}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete[lis1,Position[lis2, {x_Integer,y_}/;x!=y]]
```

> {{{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A3, T1}}}

Or, independent of `lis2`

```
lis1//Delete[#,Position[#/.assoc, {x_Integer,y_}/;x!=y]]&
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{{A3, T3}, {A3, T4}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A4, T4}, {A3, T1}}};

asoc = 
 <|A1 -> 10, A2 -> 2, A3 -> 10, A4 -> 10, T1 -> 10, T2 -> 11, T3 -> 10, T4 -> 14|>;
```

via `Position`

```
p = Position[list /. asoc, {x_, y_} /; x != y, {2}]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 2}}

Using `ReplaceAt (new in 13.1)`

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A3, T1}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
lis1 = {{{A3, T3}, {A3, T4}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A4, T4}, {A3, T1}}};

assoc = <|A1 -> 10, A2 -> 2, A3 -> 10, A4 -> 10, T1 -> 10, T2 -> 11, T3 -> 10, T4 -> 14|>;
```

---

Using `MapAt`:

```
p = Position[lis1 /. assoc, x : {__} /; DuplicateFreeQ[x], {2}]

MapAt[Nothing &, lis1, p]

(*{{{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A3, T1}}}*)
```

Or using `SubsetMap` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
ReplaceAll[SubsetMap[# - # &, lis1, p], x : {0 ..} :> Nothing]

(*{{{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A3, T1}}}*)
```

Or using `Extract` and `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[#, Alternatives @@ Extract[#, p], {2}] &@lis1

(*{{{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}}, {{A3, T3}, {A3, T1}}}*)
```